# Vanishing of section of negatively twisted line bundle

Tags: algebraic-geometry

Let $L$ be a line bundle on a smooth projective polarized variety $(X, H)$ in $\mathbb P^n$, where $H$ is the very ample divisor on $X$ giving the embedding to $\mathbb P^n$. Then I want to show that for a large enough $t\gg 0$, we have $h^0(X, L(-tH))=0$.

Can we argue as follows: If $h^0(X, L(-tH)) \neq 0$ for all $t \geq 0$, then we have  injective morphisms $\mathcal O_X(tH) \to L$ for all $t \geq 0$, a contradiction as $h^0(\mathcal O_X(tH))$ tends to infinity as $t$ tends to infinity whereas $h^0(L)$ is a finite dimensional vector space?

Or does it follow from some well-known vanishing theorem (for $h^0$ I think the Kodaira vanishing theorem do not apply here)

Any suggestion is appreciated.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Your argument certainly works(and is pretty nice!). I'll also give an alternative argument using the following proposition which I'll leave as an exercise. (I can write a proof or supply a reference if you'd like.)

> **Proposition:** Let $L$ be a line bundle on a scheme $X$. if $H^0(X, L) \neq 0$ and $H^0(X, L^{-1}) \neq 0$ then $L$ is trivial.

Since $H$ is ample, $L^{-1}(tH)$ has sections and is nontrivial for $t$ large. Hence, its dual $L(-tH)$ has no global sections by the above proposition.